# Exclude possibility of damage of Android device while chargin with another charger

Tags: charging, hardware, tablet, physical-damage

Is it true, that if I have one Android tablet with mini-usb from Philips, one Android device with mini-usb from Sony, then if I connect Philips charger to Sony charger, then it is possibility for a device to blast or cause any damage?

I heard about a story, where woman connected charger of other manufacturer and during phone call device blasted. I don't know if it is a rumor, or this is truth?
In the other hand, workmate says that solution is on a hardware level and devices detect voltage and solve this issue automatically.

Is it safe to charge with different manufacturer charger or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workmate is correct: all USB chargers supply 5 V with current limited by the design of the charger.  However, the device won't draw more current than it needs -- connect a 2 A capable device to a 500 mA charger, and it'll charge at 500 mA, but connect a 500 mA device to a 2 A charger, and it'll still only draw 500 mA.

Battery fires and explosions are caused by internal shorts and excessive current draw from the battery, not by charger mismatches (within USB voltage spec).